# Why are there not more cores in modern CPUs?

Tags: integrated-circuit, cpu

Many often confuse the meaning of Moore's Law... it refers to the number of transistors on a chip, not performance.

A while back, it became apparent that the gains from increasing clock frequency on chips was not worth the expense and chip makers started adding extra cores to CPUs.

However, the increase in the number of cores on consumer chips has not matched the increase in transistors on each chip.

I surmise that a lot of these transistors have gone into features such as prediction logic ect, because it is difficult for some workloads to be parallelized, or many programmers find parallelizing their programs too time intensive, or CPUs are optimized for existing programs.

However, from my perspective, I would like to see transistors go into increasing core count and on-chip-cache as this would benefit my programs more than marginal increases in single threaded performance given that I have no trouble writing multi-threaded code for most of my particular goals.

If I use the extra transistors for a really large cache, I will not have to make as many trips to memory, which can also be a big performance booster.

Am I incorrect as to the reason core counts do not seem to be increasing at the same rate as the number of transistors? Or is there also some diminished return for increasing core count even for easily parallelized work loads such as memory bandwidth?

Why have core counts not increased at anywhere near the rate as the number of transistors on a chip?

---

Edit: Just because a workload can be run in parallel does not mean it is an appropriate task for a GPU ect which tend to deal with doing a lot of floating point calculations. CPUs have diverse general purpose capabilities which more specialized chips lack.

An example of this could be, let's say I have a set of 50 heuristic functions I need to run against a large set of data that is already in memory.

This is easy to multi thread, give each function its own thread, and you can multi thread it further by diving up subsets of the data for each function (if the data is not highly interdependent). You could easily satiturate all the cores of even a top end Xeon processor, but you won't be able to make much use of a GPU or SIMD.

Or, just a common web application serving many different requests that do not need to be coordinated.

Or, just several different applications running on the same server for political or administrative reasons.

Comment: *I have no trouble writing multi-threaded code*. Good for you, but most of the existing code and algorithms are sequential and not fitting well into the parallelism paradigm. So the benefit of having more cores is not linear.

Comment: Have a look at the number of cores in a GPU.

Comment: It reads to me like your question's specific to Intel CPUs more than anything. Can you give several examples of the chips that lack cores. Not encountered the many who confuse Moore's Law in the way you say, though.

Comment: @EugeneSh. So my original theory is correct, it is simply to deal with existing programs / the difficulty of writing multi-threaded code?

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer No. You missed the "algorithms" part.

Comment: @NickAlexeev understood, but those cores have a very different use than CPU cores. they are not general purpose and are useful only for specific calculations. Also, they process in batches, not in a continuous linear stream

Comment: Yes. I would guess the most important parallelizable work load on consumer and business PCs is graphics, and that can use the GPU rather than the CPU. Therefore Intel is not motivated to increase parallelism on the CPU.

Comment: @TonyM Yes, I am mostly referring to intel CPUs... those tend to be what are available for my programs to run on most of the time

Comment: If your task truly fits a different model of computation, there are alternate hardware platforms available - GPUs, FPGA's, ASICs, even some "many simple processors" chips.  But don't discount using multiple "computers" if your task really and easily fits parallelism - your typical machine has bottlnecks beyond just the CPU core(s).

Comment: It's not simply programs, it's the way each core interact with each others, how they access the memory, the different hardware, etc.

Comment: About the update and specifically about the web applications - that's a valid point. This is why server-specific CPUs are usually having much more cores than the client-side ones. But the true parallelism in these applications is achieved by clustering the servers.

Comment: When you measured the performance of your code, where did you find the bottlenecks were?

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes, but the high core chips tend to be very very pricey :( In general enterprise land, you tend to mostly work with 4 core Xeons

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer Usually if you want to set up a high load server - you are a corporation which doesn't count this money.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I am not speaking of one specific application I am trying to optimize. In general, there are times I just wish I had more cores so I could spawn a new thread to do this and that without worrying that I will load all the cores.

Comment: Take That, Intel: AMD Unveils 16-core Ryzen last spring aka ‘Threadripper’ says a Enthusiast CPU user...but there’s always Skylake-x 12 core. I assume your already using water-cooled Overclocked Xeon’s . Heat is the problem per chip.

Comment: Memory bandwidth and latency are both nightmares. There exists a 1024 implementation (Adapteva) where each core only has 32K of "primary memory" and accessing global memory and other core's memory has a huge performance hit. The Taihu-light is a 256 core per chip and also suffer from memory bandwidth problems.

Comment: @user3528438 Why not use transistors to give each core a bigger cache instead of start doing things to fenagal more performance per cycle which seems to be intels approach?

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer If you give each core 1M of cache you would end up with 1GB of cache in total for 1024 cores. Even if you do that, there are 1024 cache controllers fighting for the external memory bus. On the logic level the hard thing is to give each core equal shared access to the memory address range. X86 wasn't able to scale above 4-way SMP until NUMA allows more than one memory controller per system a decade ago.

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer, there are dozens of engineers and architects working on the problem of performance optimizations and overall CPU architectures, mostly PhDs and former computer scientists/professors/academics, best of the best, with a firm grip on current and future fabrication technologies/capabilities, and with high alert of business side.  Did they forgot to invite you to their meetings?

Comment: @AliChen I am not sure how you have presumed me *asking a question* in an attempt to educate myself on the topic is an indication that I claim to posses some sort of unrealized expertise...

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer, maybe I got a false impression given your lack of trouble writing multi-threaded code, then I apologize.

Comment: @AliChen Hmmm, I can see how you may have gotten that impression from that sentence. My apologies. I do love writing parallel code, but I have a lot to learn about this particular topic

Comment: Could you give an example of your 50 heuristic functions that couldn't run well on a GPU or using SIMD?

Comment: 16, 24, 32 cores are not enough for you how many are you after?  the problem is not the cores it is getting data in and out, for a long time now the processor has not been the problem.  you can have 4 cores and struggle to get instructions/data in and out.    2, 4, 16 the cores are sitting around a good percentage of the time waiting for work.

Comment: @old_timer yes 32 core machines are available but economically still hard to get without some sort of long drawn out justification process; they are expensive. If each of those cores were less powerful because they utilized less transistors,  I could easily ask for a 16 core server as opposed to generally getting 2 to 4 without drawn out justification.

Comment: basically you want something not x86, something more efficient, but in a multicore package with fast stuff around it.  they exist but we are waiting for them in the non-tablet/phone/server market (basically the market that is going away)...

Comment: @old_timer yes. But also, they had 4 core x86 cpus 3 years ago...  since now they should have 4x as many transistors to work with, I should have a 8 x86 core cpu with very large caches available to me for the same price ;)

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer it seems like the real problem is your procurement process rather than anything electronic. Essentially you'd like more something and assume it ought to be available in your price bracket?

Comment: Did you never notice that memory prices stopped dropping nearly as fast as they used to as well? 
http://jcmit.net/memoryprice.htm
Part of this is Moore's law failing us because it's really a logistic curve and not exponential, but part of this is that the market has become inelastic.

Comment: "Yes, I am mostly referring to intel CPUs... those tend to be what are available for my programs to run on most of the time". You write only about CPUs - best to say in the question if you're talking about those for expensive workstations only. Much bigger CPU world out there than those.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a number of technical and business reasons in no particular order:

1. Memory bandwidth becomes an issue with scaling of cores. Memory
   contention can actually decrease your performance.
2. Xeon Phi is
   the platform where core hungry (and cash loaded) customers can go.
3. Most software has been designed to run well single threaded. This
   forms a chicken and egg problem. Why try and sell more cores when
   most customers can't use them? Most customers won't use them because
   hardware isn't built in a core-scaled fashion.
4. Many customers
   are more interested in IIO bandwidth. In that case, you just need
   enough cores to service IIO.
5. Intel Xeon's do have many more
   cores as well, but you'll pay a pretty penny for them in general. In
   that regard, it's simply supply and demand.
6. Because transistor count continues to scale (although not really by Moore's law anymore either), single threaded applications still dominate, and core processing power isn't the bottleneck usually, it's more effective to put those transistors to use making the cache larger and more efficient. Basically, instead of parallelizing the workload by creating more cores, the cores are now getting fed better.
7. Lack of competition in the highly parallel compute segment prevents consumer level pricing.
8. Most mainstream programming languages are ill equipped to handle parallel code well. Even those that appear to haven't seemed to find a way to easily debug parallel code. Potentially a new programming paradigm is necessary to overcome this.
9. Certain common OS's can actually suffer exponential performance loss the more forks you make so even if you have the cores, the OS handling of it ruins the usage of them. This is an extension of points 3 and 8.

Answer (score 3):

Basically as discussed: most people buy Intel-compatible processors to run their existing programs, which have minimal parallelism or may be entirely dependent on single-threaded performance.

If you want many cores, buy a GPU. Or one of these [1024-core processors.](https://www.parallella.org/2016/10/05/epiphany-v-a-1024-core-64-bit-risc-processor/) The main limiting factor then becomes *memory bandwidth*.

> given that I have no trouble writing multi-threaded code.

With which tools? What sort of algorithms?

Comment: I have no trouble too to write multi threaded code, if it has to be correct, race condition free and scalable though, I get headaches...

Comment: Most programs have minimal parallelism because they implement human logic, which is inherently sequential, not because the existing programs are bad or stupid. And computers are just accelerators of our [dis]abilities.

Comment: Even if a work load is not easily made parallel to speed it, if you have to do it for a hundred different people at a time on a server, you can often make use of more cores. Even if you are limited by IO, there is a certain cost to making a CPU core switch threads.

Comment: @AliChen Well, that is not completely true. If an algorithm *can* be parallelized, there is a parallel version of it, and it is eventually implemented if the algorithm is a bottleneck. This is why we have mathematicians and algorithmists - the guys who go beyond the average human logic and (dis)abilities.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to what has been already said, there is also an additional cost in parallelism. And I am not talking about Amdahl's law. The more cores you have in parallel the more complex the hardware becomes that has to negotiate between the cores. Some of these scale with $O(n)$ others with $O(n^2)$. This imposes an upper limit before it becomes more economic to insert another layer and use more parallel CPU's instead if more cores.

You can see these trade-offs quite nicely with Intel: there are multi-core CPU's with higher number of cores, like the Xeons that go up to 28 cores. But the Xeons are limited to about 3GHz clock speed. Most of them just do around 2.5GHz. The consumer processors go higher up in clock speed, but are limited on the number of cores.

If you have an embarrassingly parallel problem you can get one of the 8 socket motherboards and eight of those 28 core Xeons to get a whooping 224 cores in a single computer. At this point you are deep in NUMA territory and your application has to be tailored to the computer architecture you have, in order to get the full performance.